# Teamspeak connect button and choose nickname

Tags: javascript, html, teamspeak

So I want to have a connect button that let's you join the server from a Web browser and when you click it, there is a popup that lets you choose your nickname. Also I want there to be a cookie that saves the username so you don't have to enter it every time.

Can this be done with only javascript in HTML?

Thanks

Comment: To answer your question: yes, it can be done. But StackOverflow is not a request site. If your question shows that you have tried this problem yourself, we will help you. This [link](http://www.sscce.org/ ) explains what needs to be in a question before we should even attempt to answer it. W3Schools has tutorials on Javascript Cookies, and TeamSpeak themselves tell you how to connect via a web browser. Do some research, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a terrible bit of code I copied & pasted and modified for you. It is not exactly what you want but it should still work. You could make a button that opens a page in a new url with this code:

```
<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*10000000));
var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
}
return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
var user=getCookie("username");
if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user + ". You will now be redirected to our teamspeak server.");
    window.location.assign("ts3server://ts.specternetworks.com?port=9987&nickname=" +user);
} else {
   user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
   if (user != "" && user != null) {
       setCookie("username", user, 30);
   }
window.location.assign("ts3server://ts.specternetworks.com?port=9987&nickname=" +user);
}
}

</script>

<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
```